# Creating a new matrix by adjusting values within an old matrix through a for loop

Tags: python

I'd like to adjust certain values once they exceed a threshold of 180.  Here is a sample of the code:

```
mxn = Lon.shape
lon = []

for i in range(mxn[0]):
     for j in range(mxn[1]):
          if Lon[i,j]>180:
               lon.append(Lon[i,j]-360)
          elif Lon[i,j]<=180:
               lon.append(Lon[i,j])
```

Essentially, I'd like to adjust the longitude from 0-360 to -180 to 180.  When performing this loop however, it returns a single array rather than a matrix that matches the size of Lon, the original matrix.  I know there is a way to do it but I'm having a difficult time finding a good resource showing how to do it.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `Lon` a `numpy` array? I'm asking because it appears to have a `shape` attribute. In that case you shouldn't loop but rather do something like `result = (Lon + 180) % 360 - 180` which gives you the desired result in a single easily readable line and is also faster than a loop. Or to translate your method `result = np.where(Lon>180, Lon-360, Lon)`

Answer (score 0):

You are just appending all the values to a single array. Try making a sub-array in the nested `for` loop and then append that to `lon`.

```
for i in range(mxn[0]):
    sub = []
    for j in range(mxn[0])
        ....<append the values to sub>
    lon.append(sub)
```